# Good source for specific Isoforms overexpression in tumor cells (specifically, melanoma)

Tags: isoform

My group is interested in genetically engineering mice with label for the Slc45a2 gene, since "the protein is expressed in a high percentage of melanoma cell lines". (from Refseq)
How can I choose with high confidence the best isoform to use, i.e., the one that is most upregulated in melanoma cell lines?

Is there a curated database/ web-source of any kind that I can look it up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: MelGene database, https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25407435/
and then more recent studies, e.g.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7927184/ . Just to note cancer isn't my thing, I just did a pubmed search.

Comment: Many Thanks. turns out this MelGene database no longer exists. at least I couldn't find any trace of it =\